# For each for Apache FOP

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a question. This is my xml

```
<OrdersSchedulePDFView>
 <OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow>
  <ScheduleDesc>График № 6723</ScheduleDesc>
  <Ridesc>Каждый день</Ridesc>
  <Items>
     <ItemDesc>Пельмени Родной Дом Премиум 1кг пл/пак</ItemDesc>
     <ItemDesc>Пельмени Алекон Мини 900г пл/пак</ItemDesc>
  </Items>
  <Locations>
     <LocName>Ноймайер</LocName>
     <LocName>Беллинсгаузен</LocName>
  </Locations>
 </OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow>
</OrdersSchedulePDFView>
```

How can I write for-each for Items and Locations elements in xsl-fo.xsl
I need render PDF file via Apache FOP. 
This is fragment of xsl file, but it's not correct:

```
<xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFView">                
        <xsl:for-each select="./OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow">        

           <xsl:value-of select="ScheduleDesc"/>                            
            <xsl:value-of select="Ridesc"/>                                     
              <xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow">
               <xsl:for-each select="./Locations">
                  <xsl:value-of select="LocName"/>          
                </xsl:for-each>             
                <xsl:for-each select="./Items">                                                                
                 <xsl:value-of select="ItemDesc"/>
                </xsl:for-each>             

        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't undestand the question. Typically for xslt, you would try to use `template` with match and apply-templates instead of for-each. What is your expected result and what have you tried so far?? Downvote will be reverted when that is clear

Comment: To expand on Stefan's comment, Вячеслав, your question suggests that you don't have much experience with XSLT.  XSLT is a more functional language than most.  The basic processing order for template rules is often already vaguely equivalent to the `for each` statements in other programming languages.  If you can update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can better answer your needs.

Comment: There' s no matter for me if that for-each or something else. I need print in PDF  ItemDesc and LocName elements

Comment: Okay, maybe you don't understand the principle of SO being "not a code writing service". Whatever you need, show what you try and post a specific question about it. "I need print in PDF" is not helpful - you would want to produce xsl-fo and then use fop to get pdf. xsl-of usually contains more than just fo:root.

Comment: Maybe even just examine your "fragment" of XSL. XSL *is* XML. You fragment is not XML, it does not have same start and close tags ... it violates all other rules in that you have xsl:template inside another template.

Comment: I have a similar question. I want to iterate an ArrayList in my Java object, access each index and all the properties at that index to form a tabular view in pdf.